# Prove: If $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d^2|ab$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove: If $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d^2|ab$

All I have $ab = kd^2$, $k$ some integer. I'm stuck and hoping someone could walk me through this!

Comment: We have $a=da'$ for some $a'$, same for $b$, so $ab=d^2(a'b')$.

Answer (score 13):

If $d|a$, then $a = dn$ for some integer $n$.
If $d|b$, then $b = dm$ for some integer $m$.
Multiply $a$ and $b$ together: $ab = (dn)(dm) = d^2mn$ which is exactly what $d^2|ab$ means.